# BigQuery how to efficiently union two results on unique id and only keep latest

Tags: google-bigquery

What's an effective way of achieving the same result as below:

```
WITH
data_one AS (
  SELECT "abc" as id, 100 as value, TIMESTAMP("2018-11-26T14:39:51") as created UNION ALL
  SELECT "def" as id, 111 as value, TIMESTAMP("2018-11-27T14:39:51") as created
),
data_two AS (
  SELECT "abc" as id, 203 as value, TIMESTAMP("2018-11-28T14:39:51") as created UNION ALL
  SELECT "ghi" as id, 418 as value, TIMESTAMP("2018-11-28T14:39:51") as created
),
data AS (
  SELECT * FROM data_one do
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM data_two dt
)
SELECT id, value, created FROM (
  SELECT *,
  rank() over(partition by id order by created desc) rank
  FROM data
) WHERE rank = 1
```

Result of that would be:

```
+----+----- -+-------------------------+
| id | value | created                 |
+----+-------+-------------------------+
| abc| 203   | 2018-11-28 14:39:51 UTC |
+----+---------------------------------+
| def| 111   | 2018-11-27 14:39:51 UTC |
+----+-------+-------------------------+
| def| 418   | 2018-11-28 14:39:51 UTC |
+----+-------+-------------------------+
```

What if the data was really large? Is that an okay approach or is there a better one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative option would be

```
#standardSQL
WITH data_one AS (
  SELECT "abc" AS id, 100 AS value, TIMESTAMP("2018-11-26T14:39:51") AS created UNION ALL
  SELECT "def" AS id, 111 AS value, TIMESTAMP("2018-11-27T14:39:51") AS created
), data_two AS (
  SELECT "abc" AS id, 203 AS value, TIMESTAMP("2018-11-28T14:39:51") AS created UNION ALL
  SELECT "ghi" AS id, 418 AS value, TIMESTAMP("2018-11-28T14:39:51") AS created
), data AS (
  SELECT * FROM data_one do
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM data_two dt
)
SELECT id, 
  ARRAY_AGG(
    STRUCT<value INT64, created TIMESTAMP>(value, created) 
    ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1
  )[OFFSET(0)].*
FROM data t
GROUP BY id
```

or if you wanted to avoid explicit declaration of STRUCT (in case of many columns for example or to be more generic)

```
#standardSQL
WITH data_one AS (
  SELECT "abc" AS id, 100 AS value, TIMESTAMP("2018-11-26T14:39:51") AS created UNION ALL
  SELECT "def" AS id, 111 AS value, TIMESTAMP("2018-11-27T14:39:51") AS created
), data_two AS (
  SELECT "abc" AS id, 203 AS value, TIMESTAMP("2018-11-28T14:39:51") AS created UNION ALL
  SELECT "ghi" AS id, 418 AS value, TIMESTAMP("2018-11-28T14:39:51") AS created
), data AS (
  SELECT * FROM data_one do
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM data_two dt
)
SELECT * FROM data WHERE FALSE
UNION ALL
SELECT id, 
  ARRAY_AGG(
    (value, created) ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1
  )[OFFSET(0)].*
FROM data t
GROUP BY id
```

in both cases result is

```
Row id  value   created  
1   abc 203     2018-11-28 14:39:51 UTC  
2   ghi 418     2018-11-28 14:39:51 UTC  
3   def 111     2018-11-27 14:39:51 UTC
```

Comment: Would these be more performant on large datasets?

Also, to clarify it doesn't have to be a UNION, just some way of achieving the same combined result from data_one and data_two

Comment: it should be! also there is another issue you will most likely be facing when using RANK() or ROW_NUMBER() with ORDER BY type of analytic functions with large data - resource limit exceeded - because this requires moving whole group into one processing node - so if at least one id skewed - you will get that resource limit error. Also even if no skew in groups - that move of whole group to one node is affecting overall performance. use of approach in the answer  - does not require this - only top 1 from each worker node needs to be brought to one node to identify final top 1. hope this helped:)